# Problem opening Gradle project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a **Gradle** project which opened just fine on earlier **Intellij IDEA** version. But with the latest IDEA build(#IU-183.4284.148) strange things happen. Before I start describing my problem I need to say than I have both **JDK 8** and **11** installed.
I do the following:

I open up my existing project by clicking on build.gradle file:
[image]

Then I open as project:

[image]

I leave default settings here
[image]

I choose Delete existing project and import:
[image]

When the project deploys I see this tip, I haven't seen it before.
[image]

If i ignore this dialog and do not restore I see the following issues with my build.gradle file. I highlight the first one.
[image]

Moreover, the code in classes does not compile, it asks to setup JDK, but when I choose 1.8 nothing happens. It still asks to setup JDK
[image]

And on the other hand if i open the dialog and select the module nothing happens again, my build.gradle file still complains

[image]

Reimporting gradle does not help.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that not all **Java 1.8** jars were included to classpath, that is why **Setup JDK** command was ignored.
 Afted I added remaining jars all `build.gradle` issues gone away and now the code compiles.